# Does あとな時間 mean 'plus some more hours'?

Tags: listening

50 second short interview. Since I am doing this myself and I'm not a native Japanese speaker, Japanese transcript may not be 100% accurate. [Ocarina of Time Japanese Promo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLu5csyn3IQ)

-Shigeru Miyamoto interview-

10:35-11:25/43:00

> こんにちは。任天堂の宮本です。
>   Hello. I'm Shigeru Miyamoto, from Nintendo.
>
> え、本当に長い間お待たせしました。
>   Sorry for making you wait for so long.
>
> やっと「ゼルダの伝説」が完成いたしました。
>   We've finally finished another Zelda game.
>
> 基本的にはその10年前のゲームといっしょです。
>   It has the same atmosphere of the game released 10 years ago.
>   (Fundamentally it is the same as the game of 10 years ago.)
>
> けどもそれが３Ｄで、いろんなアイテムが３次元の中で**動いていく**こととかで、全然違う使い方になったりですね。
>   けどもそれが３Ｄで、いろんなアイテムが３次元の中で**合意という**こととかで、全然違う使い方になったりですね。
>   But many items are used in a completely different way now in 3-D.
>
> 非常に発展してきています。
>   It has evolved a lot.
>
> ゲーム時間はおそらく、今までのゼルダの中で最高になると思います。
>   I think this game may be the longest of all Zelda titles to date.
>
> 50時間を保証します。**あと同じか** 遊ぶかは面白させたいということで、かなりボリュームのあるゲームになっているはずです。
>                  **あとな時間** 遊ぶかは面白(い)させたいということで、かなりボリュームのあるゲームになっているはずです。
>   I can guarantee 50 hours, plus some more hours just for fun. It's a game with a lot of content.
>
> 映画のようで映画でなく、ゲームのようでゲームでな、本当に触れる映像ということをテーマに作ってきました。
>   It's not like a movie and it's not like a game either. We truly wanted to develop interactive graphics.
>
> とても楽しい世界が出来上がりましたので、皆さんで楽しんでください。
>   We've created a very fun world. Everyone, please enjoy it.

Comment: When is the timestamp on Youtube Video for the interview of the creator. Some sentences seem like repeating in the dialogue and the latter seems getting weird in the assumed transcription. *ex) *「で動いていく」** → **「で合意という」** Maybe using a machine translation and automatic transcription?

Comment: @kimi Tanaka 10:35. Interview is 50 seconds long. The only things I have to transcript this video is my ears and youtube auto-generated captions. I wish someone would correct the 日本語字幕.

Comment: The former sentence seems almost correct to me.  Also, Youtube video seems to have 「現時点{げんじてん}の動画{どうが}のURLをコピー」in this case [**the interview of miyamoto**](https://youtu.be/TLu5csyn3IQ?t=635) In this case, " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLu5csyn3IQ"  →  "https://youtu.be/TLu5csyn3IQ?t=635" changing "tube.com" into "tu.be" and adding  the timestamp "10:35" as seconds like "?t=635".

Comment: @kimi Tanaka Thanks for the reply! もう1つ質問がありますんだけど... それは「あと同じか 」または「あとな時間」ですか？どちらが正しい？

Answer (score 4):

Quick review of the scene of [the interview of 宮本茂{みやもとしげる} "shigeru miyamoto"](https://youtu.be/TLu5csyn3IQ?t=635).

I think your interpretation of '*plus some more hours*' is close.

> Transcription of Japanese: **50時間{じかん} は保証{ほしょう}します**。あと「**何時間{なんじかん}**」、遊ぶかは「**面白{おもしろ}さ** **次第{しだい}**」 ということで、かなりボリュームのあるゲームになっているはずです。
>
> My translation: **I will guarantee at least 50 hours. And, how many more hours you will be playing depends on whether you are having fun.  Anyway,** *It's a game with a lot of content.*

Comment: @ kimi Tanaka Thanks a lot! Your ears are much more in tune to Japanese than mine. The english subtitles come from whoever translated the video, not me. I am just a fan who is transcripting all the Japanese text for my own personal text file.ご苦労さん.

Comment: Thanks. I am Japanese though, I found it his speech is a bit hard to get since he is video game creator.

Comment: I have been told that 宮本 speaks 関西弁, a different 方言 from 標準語.